# Background Transparency in Microsoft Expression Blend 4

Tags: user-interface, expression-blend

I am making an application interface using Expression Blend 4. I want to remove the default title bar and main window to make the entire interface myself. I have managed to remove the title bar, but the white space at the back is still there. How can I remove this, or am I doing it wrong in general. For the record, I set AllowTransparency to true in order to remove the title bar in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Opacity="0.8"
```

Set these 3 properties